# How to prevent the affect of the router link in Angular on another element inside the <a> tag & open the link in a new tab

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
<a *ngFor="let workflow of (currentPageWorkflows$|async)"  class="template-item workflows-item" [title]="workflow.name" [routerLink]="['/workflows/designer']" [queryParams]="{ wid: workflow.hashId }" ></a>
```

This was my previous code. I wanted to add a delete workflow popup here when I clicked on a three-dot option button(located inside the workflow card). Therefore, I called a child component named 'delete-popup' to perform this task. While using the above code, I could right-click on the workflow card and open the workflow in a new tab.

After I have changed my code as below, I cannot open the workflow in a new tab after right clicking. I am getting the popup correctly. This is my updated code.

```
<a *ngFor="let workflow of (currentPageWorkflows$|async)"  class="template-item workflows-item" [title]="workflow.name" (click)="handleWorkflowClick(workflow)"  >
<div class = "custom">
    <div *ngIf ="!readonly">
        <app-delete-popup  [readonly]="readonly"(deleteClickedwf)="deleteWorkflow(workflow)">
        </app-delete-popup>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the handleWorkflowClick() method I wrote in ts file:

```
handleWorkflowClick(workflow: Workflow) {
    if (!this.readonly) {
      this.router.navigate(['/workflows/designer'], { queryParams: { wid: workflow.hashId } });
    }
  }
```

I have tried adding the router link as previous code I have given, but the issue is then when I click on three-dot option button it also navigates to the workflow designer. however, I want the delete popup to open when I click the three-dot option button. The function of three dot button correctly happens when I add a handle method

I have tried adding `target="_blank"`

Also, adding another div like this to handle the click,but none of this works.

```
<a *ngFor="let workflow of (currentPageWorkflows$|async)"  class="template-item workflows-item" [title]="workflow.name" >
<div (click)="handleWorkflowClick(workflow)(contextmenu)="handleContextMenu($event, workflow)">
    <div class = "custom">
        <div *ngIf ="!readonly">
            <app-delete-popup  [readonly]="readonly" (deleteClickedwf)="deleteWorkflow(workflow)">
            </app-delete-popup>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you in advance.